# WooCommerce output breaking my code – incorrectly closed tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, twig, timber

I’m currently developing a site with WooCommerce and utilising the Twig templating system, I am working on the archive template and have the below code as an example:

```
{% extends 'page.twig' %}

{% block before_article %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {% do action('woocommerce_before_main_content') %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block page_header %}
    <header>
        <h1>{{ title|e2 }}</h1>
        {% block below_h1 %}
            {% do action('woocommerce_archive_description') %}
        {% endblock %}
    </header>
{% endblock %}

{% block primary_block %}

    {% if products|length > 0 %}

        <div class="before-products">
            {% do action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop') %}
        </div>

        <div class="products">
            <div class="row flex">
                {% for post in products %}
                    {% include ["partials/tease-product.twig"] %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="after-products">
            {% do action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop') %}
        </div>

    {% else %}

        <div class="no-products">
            {% do action('woocommerce_no_products_found') %}
        </div>

    {% endif %}

    {% do action('woocommerce_after_main_content') %}

{% endblock  %}
```

However, the code that WooCommerce is generating via the action hooks is breaking the site as it appears to not be closing the tags properly – particularly when using the `<main>` tag.

For example, with this bit:

```
{% block before_article %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {% do action('woocommerce_before_main_content') %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The code below is not just from this section, but the whole code before the `<main>` tag is closed:

```
            <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area"><main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">        </div>
</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <article class="general-content">

                        <header>
    <h1>Collar</h1>
                            </header>

                    <div class="content">



    <div class="no-products">
        <p class="woocommerce-info">No products were found matching your selection.</p>
    </div>


</main>
```

Btw – I have temporarily removed WooCommerce breadcrumbs and that is why you don’t see them in the code above.

It seems to be doing it with most action hooks as I removed that first action hook, but I still found other misplaced `<main>` elements in the source.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

Didn’t realise those particular actions were outputting layout code, so changed it to this:

```
{% block before_article %}
    {% do action('woocommerce_before_main_content') %}
{% endblock %}
```

and then re-positioned `{% do action('woocommerce_after_main_content') %}` so it ended up in the correct spot relative to `{% do action('woocommerce_before_main_content') %}` to close the tags.